# Jquery set checkbox checked if value passed = 1

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I'm currently working on an admin panel, where via check boxes the user gets rights. The data is being passed from my main view to a modal via js script with the data-method. 
What I'm having trouble with is, when the value passed to the checkbox is 1 (Admin right given) the checkbox should be checked, but it isn't. I've checked if the value is being passed right to the modal, by changing the input to text, where I can see the right value 
What I would like to achieve: when the value from the 
DB on my main view is passed to my modal, the check boxes whose value is 1 are checked and the other ones (value=0) are not checked. Also, that this doesn't affect my ability to edit the rights of the user.

This is the approach that I've tried:

```
    <!-- Send Data to modal -->
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#edit').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
      var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
      var id = button.data('id'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
      var admin = button.data('admin');
      var expert = button.data('expert');
      var modal = $(this);
      $('#edit_form').attr('action', '{{URL::to('/')}}/AdminPanel/'+id); //No spaces!!!
      modal.find('#admin_field').val(admin);
      modal.find('#expert_field').val(expert);
    });
    </script>


    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-7 col-md-6">
        <label for="admin_field" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Admin?') }}
          <input id="admin_field" type="checkbox" class="w3-check" name="Admin">
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>

      <script type="text/javascript">
      $( document ).ready(function() {
        // auto check checkbox if value == 1
        $('.w3-check').each(function(e){
            if($(this).val() == 1){
                $(this).prop("checked", true);
            }
        });
        // Checkbox instead of on:off 1:0
        $('input:checkbox').on('change', function(){
          this.value = this.checked ? 1 : 0;
        }).change();
      });
      </script>
```

Any kind of help is much appreciated!

Comment: I guess you forgot to add value field in the checkbox

Comment: The value is being passed via jQuery, so I don't think I should define the value on the input. Also, if I debug my web page I can see that value=1

Comment: You are running your code that checks the value of the `.w3-check` elements on document.ready. The checkbox element you have shown has no value attribute in the HTML source, so where exactly do you think you should be able to read any `1` from at this point?

Comment: I cannot define the value directly in the input, because it is already being defined by       modal.find('#admin_field').val(admin);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my question, needed to change the location of the prop to my main view:

```
    <!-- Send Data to modal -->
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#edit').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
      var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
      var id = button.data('id'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
      var admin = button.data('admin');
      var expert = button.data('expert');
      var modal = $(this);
      $('#edit_form').attr('action', '{{URL::to('/')}}/AdminPanel/'+id); //No spaces!!!
            modal.find('#admin_field').val(admin).each(function(e){
          if($(this).val() == 1){
              $(this).prop("checked", true);
          }
      });
      modal.find('#expert_field').val(expert).each(function(e){
          if($(this).val() == 1){
              $(this).prop("checked", true);
          }
    });
    </script>


    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-7 col-md-6">
        <label for="admin_field" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Admin?') }}
          <input id="admin_field" type="checkbox" class="w3-check" name="Admin">
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>

      <script type="text/javascript">
      $( document ).ready(function() {
        // Checkbox instead of on:off 1:0
        $('input:checkbox').on('change', function(){
          this.value = this.checked ? 1 : 0;
        }).change();
      });
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can give this a try like this because you are running values in a loop so if it comes 0 in loop it will set the values of all the checkboxes to unchecked.

```
$('input.type_checkbox[value="1"]').prop('checked', true);
```